# Masking number_field_tag with asterisk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, passwords, numbers

I'm looking to use the `number_field_tag` as it works great on mobile devices to allow the user to input with a 10 Key interface. However, the data that they will be entering on their mobile device may contain sensitive information (i.e., part of their Social Security Number).

How can I mask the inputted data as it is being typed while maintaining the 10 Key interface? By using the `password_field_tag`, it would revert the keyboard to a standard QWERTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really ruby-on-rails specific, but you could use this in HTML to get a password input that only accepts digits and shows the numeric keyboard on some mobile devices.

```
<input type="password" pattern="\d*">
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, it doesn't work. This still displays a QWERTY. Using a Galaxy S4 with the Google Keyboard Layout.

Comment: It does work on iOS. Unfortunately I don't have a workaround for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I found a CSS solution that works on my mobile. I can use the webkit option to do this.

```
input[type=number] {
   -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Or for just a particular class as well.

```
.employee {
   -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Works on Galaxy S4 and Chrome so far with what I've tested.

Comment: The CSS solution works to obfuscate the chars, but you should also set the `pattern` attribute on the `<input type="number">` to make it work on both Android and iOS

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will definitely do so!